# Transposing items in a stack

Tags: java, stack

I am looking to move around pieces of a stack using only stacks.  For instance:

Original stack: [A,A,3,3,B,B,6,6,C,C]
Transposed stack: [B,6,6,C,C,A,A,3,3,B]

What would be a decent method of going about doing this since the Java Collections Framework has nothing like this method in the Stack class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pseudocode for it which I expect you can translate to Java no problem!

1. Make a temp stack
2. Move some items from original to temp

(So you might have A,A,3,3,B in original and C,C,6,6,B in temp.)

3. Now make a result stack
4. Put B,6,6,C,C in result stack from temp
5. Then put B,3,3,A,A into temp
6. Then put A,A,3,3,B onto result

To do these moves you'd do something like this repeatedly:
Temp.push(Original.pop()).

Answer (score 2):

Use **[Collections.rotate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,%20int))**.

```
List<String> stack = new Stack<>();
stack.addAll(Arrays.asList("A", "A", "3", "3", "B", "B", "6", "6", "C", "C"));
Collections.rotate(stack, 5);
System.out.println(stack);
```

Comment: wow, I was not aware of this API. nice :)

Comment: @rajuGT Thanks for improving answer. I also like to combine `rotate` with `subList` as in `Collections.rotate(stack.subList(2, 7), 1);`.